# Generate random number in a for loop in R software

Tags: r, for-loop, random, dataframe

I would like to ask how to generate random numbers in a `for` loop in **R** software.
I am trying to make a table with two columns, `ID` and `time`. Each `ID` has 7 `time`s: `0,1,2,3,4,5` and the last number has to be random, between 6 and 7.

```
ID<-data.frame(rep(1:100,each=7))
for (i in unique(ID)){
  ID$time <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5, x <-runif(1,6,7), 100)[ID==i]
}
```

An error message popped up:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "time", value = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA,  : 
  replacement has 8 rows, data has 700
```

Comment: your question is unclear - could you provide an example of desired output?

Comment: Are you looking for this: `ID$time <- c(replicate(100, c(0:5, runif(1,6,7))))`? Although my guess would be you are looking for `sample` instead of `runif`. Maybe: `ID$time <- c(replicate(100, c(0:5, sample(6:7, 1))))`?

Comment: Thank you! ID$time <- c(replicate(100, c(0:5, runif(1,6,7)))) is exactly what I am looking for! I am not sure how to "accept" your answer as you comment on here (im a newbie here),please let me know.

Comment: I posted it as answer. Also, added a vectorized solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Could try using `replicate`, such as

```
ID$time <- c(replicate(100, c(0:5, runif(1, 6, 7))))
```

Althoguh `replicate` is wrapper for `sapply` which is basically a hidden `for` loop. Instead, you could also try a vectorized approach, such as:

```
ID$time <- 0:6
ID[ID$time == 6, "time"] <- runif(100, 6, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
 set.seed(123)
 ID <- data.frame( time = c(0,1,2,3,4,5), x = runif(100,6,7))
```

You don't want to use '<-' for the arguments to `data.frame`

But maybe it's this that you want:

```
  ID <- data.frame( time = rep( c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), each=100) , x = runif(700,6,7))
```

(it's always a good idea to describe in a natural language what it is that you want.)